# MVC routing issue to make two methods work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing, mvcroutehandler

I have product controller and two methods edit and fileupload.
what should I do in my route config to make these two work.

Product/6 (for editing productid 6)

Product/Fileupload (for uploading file).

my current route in routeconfig is as follows:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
        name: "editProducts",
        url: "Product/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Edit", id=UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following routes (in this order) before the default. I have assumed that you always need an ID to edit so the `id` parameter is not optional (but you could make it so) and I was not sure if you needed to pass a parameter to the FileUpload method

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Upload",
  url: "Product/FileUpload/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "FileUpload", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "editProducts",
  url: "Product/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Edit" }
);
```

Comment: Thank you. i adopted the above technique

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "editProducts",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Edit", id=UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: are you using the form authentication or asp.net membership?

Comment: Thanks Hiren. the above solution by Stephen Muecke helped me. though i want to make that more generic. but it solved my problem for now

Answer (score 0):

Add tahe following routes by same order before the default.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "fileupload",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Fileupload"}
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "editProducts",
        url: "Product/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Edit", id=UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```